# quitar componente especifico de un ngfor en angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un array con 4 datos y quiero mostrar esos datos mediante un `*ngFor`, hasta aquí todo bien, los muestro sin problemas, lo que yo quiero es que al hacer clic en un botón que esta dentro de ese componente el dicho componente tenga una animación y cuando termine esa animación, sacarlo directamente del dom y ya no mostrarlo mas, aquí una porción de lo que tengo.

```
<div class="box" *ngFor="let data of dat">
     <div class="container-data">
          <span>{{ data }}</span>
     </div>
     <div class="container-button">
          <button (click)="quitarCaja()">quitar caja </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**aquí el component.ts**

```
 dat = ["data1","data2","data3","data4"]
 quitarCaja(){
   //aqui la logica para animar y quitar el componente
 }
```

En este caso lo que se tendría que quitar es el div que contiene la clase `box` 
no me llevo bien con angular, les agradecería si me ayudan

Comment: Hola, aquí te paso un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebxcgq) que hice en StackBlitz con los mismos datos que subiste.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías programar una animación con javascript y esperar a que termine para quitar el elemento.

Pero podrías hacerlo "a la Angular" que básicamente es manejar la data y dejar que el DOM reaccione a los cambios.

Para agregar animaciones utilizamos el modulo de "@angular/animations".
Para ello necesitas especificar:

- Los "disparadores" (triggers). Básicamente, un id para los elementos que van a ser animados.
  Estos se especifican en el template:

```
<div class="box" *ngFor="let data of dat" @miTrigger>
     <div class="container-data">
          <span>{{ data }}</span>
     </div>
     <div class="container-button">
          <button (click)="quitarCaja(data)">quitar caja </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

En este caso `@miTrigger` está especificando que ese div será el que se estaremos animando.

- Las animaciones. Estás se especifican en la metadata del componente.

Aquí podrías leer en la [documentación de Angular acerca de animaciones (en inglés)](https://angular.io/guide/animations). Pero te lo puedo resumir en que podemos usar lo siguiente:

```
animations: [
    trigger('miTrigger', [
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('0.5s', style({opacity: 0, height: 0}))
      ])
    ]),
]
```

En resumen, especificamos que para el trigger `miTrigger` vamos a usar una transición de salida (`:leave`) para que cuando el elemento desaparezca animar la altura y opacidad (ambos a cero) con una duración de medio segundo.

Con todo lo anterior solo te queda quitar los elementos del array, esto hará que el `*ngFor` actualice el DOM; disparando así la animación que especificamos.

---

Para ver un demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuamz8

Comment: tu metodo es valido para animar un array que contiene objetos? es decir, en vez de quitar un string, quitar un objeto con datos

Comment: Sí, es válido. En cualquier caso `:leave` es una transición de salida de objetos del DOM. Sin importar cual sea la data que esté representando.